# View reputation without having to click in Mobile Stack Overflow

Tags: feature-request, mobile-web

For the safety of all the other drivers on the road, is it possible to display our rep on the SO mobile version within the top bar, without having to try to click the small down arrow to display inbox contents?

Comment: Note to self: stay off Murietta roads.

Comment: Lol you are wise.

Comment: For the safety of all the other drivers on the road? Why are you using your phone while driving? I hope you get a ticket. O.O

Comment: For every second a driver doesn't have his full attention on the road, the possibility of an accident rises.

Comment: -1 because you're going to cause an accident.

Comment: +1 because all these goofballs missed the joke...

Comment: Wow. It is 80% a joke, 20% truth. If you are unfamiliar with southern california traffic there are times when you don't move for minutes at a time. During this time I tend to check email and SO. It's not like I'm answering questions whilst cruising along at 80 mph.

Comment: Hmm, that's weird. I have better luck answering questions at 80 mph because there's nothing changing in front of me. When the traffic is start-and-go, I'm always failing to notice that I need to pull forward.

Answer (score -3):

Just for this question you should loose your driver licence. What for Heaven's sake did this site to you, that you have to watch your reputation permanently?

If this should be a joke like ["The Establishment"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/153008/the-establishment) thinks, then I don't get it either. In times where so many people buy themselves expensive cars and do not want to spend a cent on a hands-free equipment for their phone, or try to read SMS while driving, I can't find the joke in such a question. Also because of my former study.

But to be a little bit constructive and safe some soles on your daily route:

- Use a shortcut on your phone for the page: `http://stackoverflow.com/users/{yourid}/`
- Much better: Use the [Stackexchange API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs) with the function [/me](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/me). Take the value `reputation` out of the answer, together with bandages *(because this would probably be your next question)* and display it in the biggest letters you can. [Here my demo for you](http://jsfiddle.net/j69Cm/). It's just a demo but it works if you fill in an [access token](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/js-lib) and [key](https://stackapps.com/apps/oauth/register) <sup>[1]</sup>
- And the best solution: Use the [Stackexchange API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs) together with a [Text-To-Speech API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_to_speech) and let your reputation be read for you.

---

<sup>[1]</sup> or for demo like i did you can get this info out of the demos in the documentation :)

Comment: I somehow assume the question asker is not *only* interested in the reputation, but just wants to see it while using the site.

Comment: @arjan so he wants to read whole questions while driving? I thought about he want to open the startpage to look at his reputation while driving, but reading questions while driving... Loosing his driver license isn't enough for doing this!

Comment: I think you're focusing too much on one sentence, which most likely is just a joke. You can use comments to comment on that, or to ask for clarification. It's not relevant to the feature request, hence not relevant to any answer I'd say.

Comment: I think it would be a good feature, as there is no reason to check inbox just to see your rep. People are OVER reacting about the "mostly a joke" about doing it while driving (realistically sitting in traffic).